# Flowchart for two recursive functions

Tags: recursion, flowchart

I have two simple functions:

a)

```
drawRight(x){ // where x is integer
      if(x == 0 )
         draw();
      else{
         drawRight(x-1);
         doSomething();
         drawLeft(x-1);
      }
   }
```

b) (very similar to a) )

```
drawLeft(x){ // where x is integer
      if(x == 0 )
         draw();
      else{
         drawRight(x-1);
         doSomething2();
         drawLeft(x-1);
      }
   }
```

My question is: is it even possible to draw flowchart if i call e.g drawRight(5) ? I did flowchart for only self calling recurvive function but cant find solution for this one.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A recursive function is usually called and processed using a stack in any programming language I know of. The flowchart might not exactly follow the rules a programming language follow to run a code with recursive functions, but it shows how a flowchart can run a recursive snippet:

[image]

Note that functions are added to the stack in the reversed order. For example, if `drawRight` calls `drawRight`, `doSomething`, and `drawLeft`, they will be added to stack as `drawLeft`, `doSomething`, and `drawRight`. This way `drawRight` will be called first, then `doSomething`, and `drawLeft` last. The executions would happen as expected.

The flowchart would have less wires if case is used instead of conditional element.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the flowchart would look like this. I did it  for drawRight(2), as it gets pretty massive very quickly

[image: Flowchart]

The actual order of terminal calls would then be

- draw
- doSomething
- draw
- doSomething
- draw
- doSomething2
- draw

Comment: I`m not sure how to call in English diagram i need  properly, maybe block diagram. I need something like this:
http://prntscr.com/8mo9mz
and if it's possible to complete it would "work" for every 'n' value