# Flow chart - recursion

Tags: recursion, flowchart

I want to create a flow chart for a recursion function. But the problem is there are two lines of code that call the function and cause a recursion.
In the code it might look straightforward

```
function(array):
  if (base case) do: // base case check
     return
  if (array.length > 1) do:
     function(array= elements from 1 to array.length/2) // first call 
     function(array= elements from array.length/2 to array.length) // second call
```

but I am not sure how to show this in flow chart
I thought of doing something like this:

[image]

it doesn't look like there is an order of the calls and in general I don't know what to show if the array.length check (the second check) is false

by the way I am using https://app.diagrams.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can use stacks to represent the executions in a flowchart:

[image]

I have answered similar question with more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68241088/1927695